# Undefined Array Key

Tags: php

I am running into this error:

```
Warning: Undefined array key 1
```

In this particular script:

```
if (1 > count($args)) {
    echo 'Expecting one argument: shopping list slug.' . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}

$slug = $args[0];
$filter = $args[1];
$query = Container::getInstance()->getShoppingListDetailQuery();

if (!isset($args[1])) {
    return
    ($list = $query->execute(new GetShoppingListDetailRequest($slug, 'not-completed')));
}

try {
    $list = $query->execute(new GetShoppingListDetailRequest($slug, $filter));
} catch (ShoppingListNotFoundException $ex) {
    echo sprintf("Shopping list '%s' does not exist.", $slug) . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}

if ($list->isEmpty()) {
    echo sprintf(
        "Shopping list '%s' has no items.",
        $list->getName(),
    ) . PHP_EOL;
    exit(0);
}

echo sprintf('%s (%d items):', $list->getName(), $list->count()) . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($list->getItems() as $item) {
    echo sprintf(
        "%s. [%s] %s",
        $item->getId(),
        $item->isCompleted() ? 'X' : ' ',
        $item->getName(),
    ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

What I am trying to do is if the user doesn't type in a second argument and just the title of the shopping list, then the default option of just showing the not-completed items of the list will be shown to the terminal. I also don't understand why it says it isn't defined because I did define it with

```
$filter = $args[1];
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The statement `if (1 > count($args)){exit;}` literally means "if more than one item exists in the array then exit", so the array will never have two keys, `0` and `1`.

Comment: @ChrisHaas That would mean that _no_ argument exists, right?

Comment: Yoda-Style conditions are sometimes hard to read.

Comment: Right, so it does make sense that it needs to be 2 >count($args) however it doesn't show the default when I run the script which is showing not-completed items, though when I manually type I want not-completed items in the terminal it does show them, as it does with all items and completed items.

Comment: You're using `$filter = $args[1];` _before_ `if (!isset($args[1])) {`

Comment: @brombeer, hah, yeah, that is a better way to put it!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to read command line arguments
Then you should be using

> $argv

Read more from the [official php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

If you have previously defined $args however, then please provide the code where you first defined it.